# Too many connections in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to learn Hibernate and I wrote the simplest Person Entity and I was trying to insert 2000 of them. I know I'm using deprecated methods, I will try to figure out what are the new ones later.

First, here is the class Person:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

        private int id;
        private String name;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "person")
        @TableGenerator(name = "person", table = "sequences", allocationSize = 1)
        public int getId() {
                return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
                this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
                return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
        }

}
```

Then I wrote a small App class that insert 2000 entities with a loop:

```
public class App {

        private static AnnotationConfiguration config;

        public static void insertPerson() {
                SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory();
                Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
                session.beginTransaction();
                Person aPerson = new Person();
                aPerson.setName("John");
                session.save(aPerson);
                session.getTransaction().commit();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
                config.addAnnotatedClass(Person.class);
                config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml"); //is the default already
                new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true); //print and execute
                for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
                        insertPerson();
                }
        }

}
```

What I get after a while is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
>
> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections

Now I know that probably if I put the transaction outside the loop it would work, but mine was a test to see what happens when executing multiple transactions. And since there is only one open at each time, it should work.

I tried to add  `session.close()` after the commit, but I got

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.SessionException: Session was already closed

So how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not about `Session`s and transactions, it's about `SessionFactory`. You create a new `SessionFactory` on each iteration and don't close it.

Usually you need only one instance of `SessionFactory` per application, so that you should create it outside of the loop, and close it explicitly when your application stops.

Obtaining `Session`s and work with transactions inside the loop is correct.

Comment: Great, that was the problem, thank you. Quite obvious in hindsight... So later I could make it a Spring singleton, or, after I get a grasp of hibernate, do you suggest me to study [Spring Data](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data)?

Comment: @stivlo: Yes, in Spring application the typical approach is to create `SessionFactory` as a singleton (there is a special `LocalSessionFactoryBean` helper class for it). Regarding Spring Data, I'm not familiar with it.